# Understanding of the term "thread"

Tags: c, multithreading, language-lawyer, terminology

I have a trouble understanding of the term "thread".

Consider C11, 5.1.2.4 Multi-threaded executions and data races, 1:

> Under a hosted implementation, a program can have more than one *thread of execution*
> (or *thread*) running concurrently.

Question: does "thread of execution" (or "thread") implies only a thread created using `thrd_create` (`<threads.h>`) or `main` (hosted environment) or `<name of the function called at program startup>` (freestanding environment)?

Reason of the question: the following questions:

- Is thread created via call of interrupt handler a thread in a C sense?
- Is thread created using your own mechanism (e.g [A Minimal User-Level Thread Package](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/%7Edwjones/opsys/threads/)) a thread in a C sense?
- Is thread created using `pthread_create` (i.e. POSIX thread) a thread in a C sense?
- Is thread created using [`CreateThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread)/[`_beginthread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/beginthread-beginthreadex?view=msvc-170) a thread in a C sense?

Comment: It doesn't matter how it is created. A "thread" is a common computing term that is not specific to C, so it is not defined by C standard. But it is defined in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) for example.

Comment: I'm going to go against the grain here. As far as the standard cares, the only "real" threads are ones you create using the C standard library. Something else might create a thread that's similar enough for some (possibly even all) of the same things to apply, but then again they may not. C threads are enough like Posix threads that they're probably close to interchangeable. Windows threads, less so.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, I don't know about "call of interrupt handler," but the other three cases are real. The question is, when the target is a multi-CPU computer, will the toolchain and the runtime-support library and the threading library all work together with the hardware to guarantee a  useful [_memory model_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_(programming)) for the program? If you're using a standard C compiler and standard library calls to create threads, then the answer should be "yes." If you're using some other library, then finding the answer may be more of a research problem...

Comment: ...And, not portable. You'll have to research it separately for each different platform that you target, and you'll have to do it again for each time you you want to build with a new toolchain, and maybe for each new upgrade of the OS that you (or your customers) want to accept. Sticking with the standard is a lot simpler!!

Comment: @SolomonSlow: Let me give an example. If you're using multiple threads, you typically need to use thread-local storage for a few functions like `strtok` and `rand`.  Before C11, Microsoft included a `beginthread` that called `CreateThread` and allocated thread local storage for you. But if you just call `CreateThread` directly, using those functions from multiple threads will break (and yes, you can imitate `beginthread` by allocating thread local storage, if you know what functions need it--but about the only way to know is to look at the source to `beginthread`).

Comment: In C11, I'd expect `thrd_create` to act pretty much like `beginthread`, but (again), calling `CreateThread` directly can and will break things.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, I'm just saying, that doesn't make threads created with `CreateThread` any less "real." But it makes using them more risky, and there's no benefit to accepting that risk if you're writing new code for a platform where the standard facility is supported. But let me offer a counterexample: You're developing embedded firmware, using the hardware vendor's toolchain. It's not up-to-date with the standard. If you want to use threads, you use the vendor's library calls to create them, and you trust the hardware vendor to ensure that the toolchain, library, and harware all work together.

Comment: They are a real thing of some sort, but they're *not* a "thread" as the term is used in the C standard.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Taking into account "non <threads.h> threads" does it mean that an implementation with no support of `<threads.h>` is required to support thread local storage duration? Example: is `exp` function (`math.h`) required to be reentrant (i.e. the `errno` is `#define errno (*__errno())` rather than `extern int _Errno;` followed by `#define errno _Errno`) when being called in a thread created by e.g. `pthread_create`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Understanding of the term "thread"

"Thread" is a word with many definitions. What it means depends on whose definition you're using, and sometimes one person's "thread" looks nothing like another person's "thread" (e.g. for GPUs a "thread" is often not a "thread of execution" at all and is more like a CPUs "SIMD lane").

If you try to find the common features of different definitions of "thread" used for computers (and ignore outliers, and ignore its use for textiles - "thread of cotton"); you might end up with something like "a thread is a set of instructions (with control flow) that appears to (but might not literally) execute concurrently with other threads".

> Is thread created via call of interrupt handler a thread in a C sense?

Interrupts are normally considered "(involuntary) control flow change" and not a thread (e.g. like a thread calling a function, just not as a normal/voluntary part of the program).

> Is thread created using your own mechanism (e.g A Minimal User-Level Thread Package) a thread in a C sense?

In the C sense, yes. From the perspective of code using the user-level thread package it's "threads" (and from the perspective of the OS/kernel it might be considered a single thread).

> Is thread created using pthread_create (i.e. POSIX thread) a thread in a C sense?

Yes, `pthread_create()` is one way to create a thread in the C sense.

> Is thread created using CreateThread/_beginthread a thread in a C sense?

Yes, these are just more ways to create a thread in the C sense (it's just that they're not as portable). In some cases `pthread_create()` could be considered a "more portable" wrapper around whatever the OS provides (e.g. `CreateThread()` on Windows, `clone()` on Linux, etc).

Ironically, `thrd_create()` that was introduced in C11 can be considered an "even less portable wrapper", because most people using C are using older versions of C (e.g. C90). This is partly because some platforms (Windows) don't officially support any later version of C (and partly because people that want more modern languages switched to more modern languages).